# iOS 9 Xcode 7 GM Cannot Submit to App Store iTunes Connect - Submission Deployment Target must be 8.4, cannot be 9.0

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I just built my app with Xcode 7 GM with a deployment target of 9.0, is there some document from Apple that states you have to use 8.4 and not 9.0?

When I try to submit this app for review I get the message:

> Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in MYAPP.app/MYAPP is 9.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 8.4.
>   The app's Info.plist file must contain a valid value for the MinimumOSVersion key. For more information, see the Information Information Property List Key Reference.
>   Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in MYAPP.app/PlugIns/MYAPP_EXT.appex/MYAPP_EXT is 9.0 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 8.4.
>   Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software.

Has anyone submitted a build with Xcode 7 GM and a deployment target of 9.0 or 8.4?

UPDATE 9/10 7pm PST: 
Apple is now allowing the submission in iTunes Connect, but a few minutes later I receive an email with the same warning.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent submission for "MY_APP". To process your submission, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> This bundle is invalid - The value provided for the key MinimumOSVersion '9.0' is not acceptable.
>
> Invalid Toolchain - New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect. Choose the new binary on the app’s Details page in My Apps on iTunes Connect, and click Submit for Review.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

UPDATE 9/11:
Now getting this error:

> Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software.

UPDATE 9/11:
I was just able to successfully submit the app and it went to Waiting for Review so you can now submit apps. This is resolved by Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/news/

> Submit Your Apps Today
>   September 11, 2015
>
> You can now submit your apps that take advantage of the latest features in iOS, OS X, and watchOS. Build your apps using Xcode 7 GM seed, test with the GM seeds of iOS 9, OS X El Capitan, and watchOS 2, and submit them for review. Learn how to prepare your apps for the App Store.

Used 10.10.4 and Xcode 7 GM with a deployment target of 9.0.

Comment: I think this is the same issue from the Apple Dev Forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16979

Comment: Based on the dev forum, an update will be posted to https://developer.apple.com/news/ and Apple should allow submissions in 1-2 days.

Comment: There seems to be no active fix as of now. I am getting "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software." and I am using the latest Xcode 7 GM, and OS X 10.11.1 . No fix, anyone?

Comment: Btw I never got any email from Apple... just that error in ITC on app submit. No clue as to WHAT version of any software is old/too new or whatever.

Comment: @Jonny: OS X 10.11.1 is still in beta. I'm having the same setup and am experiencing the problem.

Comment: @Jonny I had success with OSX 10.10.4, I have a feeling the beta OSX is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just able to successfully submit the app and it went to Waiting for Review so you can now submit apps. This is resolved by Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/news/

> Submit Your Apps Today
>   September 11, 2015
>
> You can now submit your apps that take advantage of the latest features in iOS, OS X, and watchOS. Build your apps using Xcode 7 GM seed, test with the GM seeds of iOS 9, OS X El Capitan, and watchOS 2, and submit them for review. Learn how to prepare your apps for the App Store.

Used 10.10.4 and Xcode 7 GM with a deployment target of 9.0.

Comment: Is this really correct?Why would OS X El Capitan not be allowed to submit? Does this mean that Yosemite is ACTUALLY still required?

Comment: @Jonny El Captain is a beta, so its methods and APIs are not finalized, how can you build GA software on a beta which is still changing under your Xcode?

Comment: @Jonny  The message from Apple says, "Don't submit apps built with beta software." El Captain is a beta.... seems clear to me.

Comment: I got it right in the end. I made sure that I had the El Capitan GM installed, then it worked. The trick is to get out of the beta program, by turning that off in the preferences to avoid installing any beta software.

Comment: To make it clear: my mistake was using a beta update of El Capitan. The GM seed works fine.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, as of right now, Apple is not accepting iOS 9 apps yet. This should happen soon. Until then, I'd suggest testing using the GM builds of iOS 9 and watchOS 2 using TestFlight. This is what I am doing.

Comment: I have no problems testing the apps. The app is ready to go, I'm just trying to get it into the App Store ASAP after iOS 9 is released to the public. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have just uploaded my iOS9 app to the app store, important thing is your Xcode should not be beta version make sure you are building archive with stable Xcode version, and your app supports 64 bit devices

Answer (score 5):

I've experienced all the same issues so far. At this point, I'm wondering if upgrading to El Capitan GM may make a difference, per this slightly older thread:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/40805#40805

**UPDATE 09/11/2015 @ 2:27pm (EST):**

In regards to the "Invalid ToolChain" email, the last post in the thread, provided by **Temamedia** reads:

> El Capitan GM, xCode 7 GM, same problem here.

This actually suggests that having the GM OS doesn't help.

However, **opswhisperer**'s comment also suggests that running on a Yosemite virtual machine doesn't cause the same issues:

> I just built mine from a Yosemite VM and it worked fine, Apple
>   accepted it.

Thank you **ci_**, for the tip!

**UPDATE 09/11/2015 @ 5:00pm (EST):**

Latest message when trying to submit app:

> Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the
>   public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later.
>   Don't submit apps built with beta software.

Comment: If it helps I'm running 10.10.4 from that thread its not really clear is using Yosemite or El Capitan was actually a solution to the issue, maybe I missed the comment.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I expect there's not much of a point to me upgrading to GM yet then. :(

Comment: How about summing up what to do at this point? I have tried lots of different El Capitan versions. I can't believe Apple does not support El Capitan for submitting iOS apps? I've even heard Yosemite and Xcode 7 do not play well together so I specifically updated everything.

Comment: @Jonny use a non beta version of OSX, I don't see a single user who has had success with using El Capitan. Yosemite and Xcode 7 GM work just fine together.

Comment: Regarding the invalid toolchain, you get the error if you are on the beta version of OS X. Here is a little trick you can use to get around it. It works perfectly! https://georgegarside.com/blog/ios/submit-apps-built-beta-xcode/

Answer (score 1):

Per the latest post by **chuckc192000**, on the thread you provided:

> Apple always sends an email out to everyone when they're ready to
>   accept submissions for new iOS versions (at least they have in the
>   past).  Don't submit apps until you get that email.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16979

Comment: Email is out since weeks (or so) and nothing helps today.

Comment: Uploading a binary does not necessarily mean submitting. You upload binaries to iTunesConnect for TestFlight testing as well.